# Missing points in HighCharts when applying event to exported button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/gJSUX/embedded/result/) I tried to make a button to switch between a set of values and the relative cumulative sum.

the `highchart` option I used is

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        'exportTo': {
            _id: 'exportTo',
            symbol: 'diamond',
            text: 'Show Cumulative',
            onclick: function () {
                if (!cumulative) {
                    this.series[0].setData(cumcum(data1));
                    this.series[1].setData(cumcum(data2));
                    cumulative = true;
                } else {
                    this.series[0].setData(data1);
                    this.series[1].setData(data2);
                    cumulative = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However if you try to select some points and **then** select `Show Cumulative` you'll see that the points after those just selected are missing, and when click again they come back (and so on).

How do you guys explain this? It's prob easy but I'm very new to JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `cumcum` function.

When you select a point, it changes the item in the array from a number to an object like this:

```
[ 7, 6.9, 9.5, { selected: true, y: 14.5 }, 18.2, ... ]
```

So, you have to change your acumulator to something that detects if `data[i]` is a number or an object and act accordingly:

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (typeof data[i] === 'object') {
        res[i] = res[i - 1] + data[i].y;
    } else {
        res[i] = res[i - 1] + data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You were great! Thanks!! One question, in the argument of my function ( which was supposed to be `cumsum` :-) ) I pass the original array coming from ajax, I don't refer to `this....`. So I thought that the arrays `data1` and `data2` were always the same...

Comment: I really don't know but from the results I'd say `data1` and `data2` are being captured somewhere and Highcharts gets references to them and not copies.

Comment: For instance, in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/gJSUX/2/) where I'm using jsFiddle's echo functionality to simulate an AJAX response, you'll see `data1` and `data2` captured in a closure if you put a breakpoint inside the `onclick` handler.

Comment: Yep! change by reference the only way! Thanks a million! I better make a copy of them, (I need them elsewhere either :-) )